# Some of my questions haven't been answered. Is there something I can do?

Tags: discussion

The title says it all. @nbro has helped in increasing clarity in my questions. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to attract attention to your posts/questions, you can start a **bounty** on them. You should carefully read [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), which explains what a bounty is and what the consequences are (i.e. you will not get your reputation back even though you're not satisfied with the answers or it's not even guaranteed that you will get an answer at all).

Answer (score 1):

Bounties can be an incentive, by my sense is they are mostly attractive to people new to a given stack, who want to build initial rep quick.  (There are good reasons for this, as it confers a series of privileges.)

When I'm new on a stack, I seek out questions I can answer to get basic mod privileges quickly, so I can start doing some "housekeeping" on those stacks when time permits.

My sense is that users with sufficient rep often transition to answering the questions that pique their interest, or occupy a subject in which they feel it's important to educate.

Since your rep is low, and you don't have a lot to spend, I might reserve bounties only for critical questions.

*(My own questions typically don't do well on any stack, and I've just had to accept that, but I still find participation in the stack community incredibly rewarding:)*